# Running parallel tests with Pabot

Tags: robotframework, parallel-testing

I have installed the pabot lib but still struggling to trigger my testcases.

Can someone please suggest how to start the testcase run.

I ran it like below :

`C:\Python27\SampleScripts\DataDrivenApproach\KITE>pabot Pabt.robot --processes 2
 tests`

And got this :

`get_suite_names: output_file='.\pabot_results\suite_names.xml' does not exist
No tests to execute
Elapsed time: 0 minutes 0.6 seconds`

Comment: does the folder `tests` in the current directory have any test suites in it?

Comment: Hey!! I just ran >pabot testsuite1.txt testsuite2.txt and it worked .